# When a crash occurs, how can I upload a log file?

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

The ability to upload a log file immediately after an exception has proven crucial in the past for quickly debugging problems in *complex* systems.
Does fabric's crashlytics allow this?

Answer (score 1):

Fabric doesn't send a crash right away after a crash. Only when the app is relaunched does a crash get sent.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. You can use logging methods to log information: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html#custom-logging. The logs will be associated with the crash and uploaded on the next launch after the crash.

Comment: Is there a limit on how much logging data can be uploaded?

Comment: To make sure that sending crash reports has the smallest impact on a user’s devices, Crashlytics logs have a maximum size of 64 KB. When a log exceeds 64 KB, the earliest logged values will be dropped in order to maintain this threshold.

Comment: Is there a way to increase the limit ?

Comment: There isn't an option to increase the limit